# Сильно ли уменьшится потребление памяти если заменить все переменные int на byte?

Tags: java, оптимизация, переменные, byte, int

Допустим, в каком нибудь крупном (или нет) проекте сотни (или тысячи, или десять) штук переменных `int`, которые не переходят предел значений в `-128..127`. Если их всех заменить на переменные `byte`, изменит ли это расход памяти? И вообще, стоит ли писать код с переменными `byte`, или можно не заморачиваться и писать везде `int`?

Comment: Если у вас сотни таких переменных, то они, видимо, должны быть организованы в массив(ы)?

Comment: @MBo зачем? Они же не в одном классе все используются, я просто говорю про проект. На каждый цикл for приходится по одной переменной.

Comment: Загляните в компилятор, он Вам даст точный ответ по потреблению памяти целочисленными типами и их преобразование

Comment: От замены переменных для for выигрыша не будет, они ведь обычно локальные - выделяются на стеке при входе в блок, освобождаются после него. Кроме того, компилятор под капотом (не скажу про Java, но думаю, что там тоже) часто использует переменную цикла родного типа (например. int32) для данной ОС, даже если указан байт/short

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не изменится из-за выравнивания адресов (скажем все адреса должны быть кратными 8 или 16 - зависит от JIT). Разве что массивы могут стать меньше, в чём я тоже не вполне уверен. Вполне может быть, что JIT выравнивает и адреса элементов массивов. Кроме того в арифметических выражениях с `byte` можно нарваться на неочевидное поведение, связанное с преобразованием типов. Скажем вы вызываете метод, который возвращает `int` и пытаетесь удалить этот `int` из `Set<Byte>`. У вас всё скомпилируется и даже не будет бросать исключения, `int` будет бокситься в `Integer`, но ничего удаляться не будет. Вы конечно можете кастить все `int` в `byte`, но наверняка где-то забудите или пропустите и получите неочевидный баг.